# Send Pixels From MCU to HDMI

Tags: microcontroller, pic, video, hdmi, monitor

I would like to send pixel data from a MCU (PIC24 or PIC32) to a LCD computer monitor via HDMI.

Ideally, I would only update frames as needed and not have to transmit them continually.

Can it be done easily enough? What are my options?

Answer (score 2):

HDMI requires continuous transmission. You'll need to transmit your data from the MCU to a separate graphics controller that contains a frame buffer, which can then produce the stream of HDMI data for the monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Further to Dave's answer, have a search on Hackaday.com and Dangerous Prototypes for the term "HDMI", some people have created microntroller/FPGA devices that can output HDMI etc. but it's not simple, it may be that you use one of those devices as a "graphics card" attached to your micro to drive HDMI.

Comment: Using an external driver and filling the frame buffer from your microcontroller is the sensible way to do it at low volume.